# Bootstrap modal popup upon failed login

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, bootstrap-modal

I have a login page (login.html) that calls a php with POST method to valid login credentials, which works just fine. If the email an password are incorrect, then in my current implementation, an alert pops up and the page reloads. I would like to know how to activate a modal instead of said popup.

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-confirm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <div class="icon-box">
          <i class="material-icons">&#xE5CD;</i>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body text-center">
        <h4>Ooops!</h4> 
        <p>Something went wrong. File was not uploaded.</p>
        <button class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Try Again</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Complete PHP File:

```
<?php
   $email = $_POST['email'];
   $pwd = $_POST['pwd'];


   $conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','','rm');
   if($conn->connect_error){
      die('Connection Error: '.$conn->connect_error);
   }
   else{
      $sql = "select * from superfan  where email='".$email."' and password='".$pwd."' ";
      $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
      $records = mysqli_num_rows($result);
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
      if ($records==0)
      {
         echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
         echo '$(document).ready(function() {';
         echo '$("#myModal").modal("show");';
         echo '});';
         echo '</script>';
      }
      else
      {
         header('location:index.html');
      } 
         mysqli_close($conn);
      }
?>
```

Comment: Where are the inputs?

Comment: as soon as you POST, you leave the current page. Therefore I assume you get a blank page, which upon showing the source, will have only that script stuff. And an error in the console, since there wont be any jQuery

Comment: also, can PHP run in these HTML files, or HTML only?

Comment: if not, rename them .php

Comment: What isn't working the way you'd like it to? You didn't say.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner input is from a form. Havent included the form in the post but the login and validation work. The modal doesnt pop up, it doesnt get activated.

Comment: @delboy1978uk i tried running it in the same file, it didnt work.

Comment: rename your html files .php, update any links, and try again. if you can get php running in the file youre on the way to fixing it

Comment: Where does the POST request get sent to? The same page, or another file? If it's another file, you'll need to redirect back to the page with the modal, ideally with a hash on the end (ex: `https://yoursite.com/login#failed`), then use JavaScript on that page to check if there is a `#failed` on the end, and *then* trigger the modal.